# Unable to use React.memo in React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use React.memo for optimization in react native.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const Memo = React.memo(function() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Ok</Text>
    </View>
  );
});
class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Memo />;
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

It gives following error:

> TypeError : undefined is not a function (evaluating `render(nextProps)`).
>   This error is located at : 
>   in Demo(at renderApplication.js:34) 
>   in RCTView(at View.js:44 )

Can we use React.memo in react native?

Comment: What version of react-native are you using? My guess is that you are using a version older than 16.8 which doesn't support hooks. Is that the case?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22366 
this is a realted issue, seems no explaination yet

Answer (score 3):

The "component" you are trying to memoize isn't a correct react component, it isn't being passed any props. The react `memo` HOC is also only for functional components, use `PureComponent` for class-based components

You need to ensure you are using the current version of react that introduced the `memo` HOC, and use it as such:

```
import React, { Component, memo } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const Demo = props => (
  <View>
    <Text>Ok</Text>
  </View>
);

export default memo(Demo); // memo HOC memoizes return component based on state and props!
```

[React memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Answer (score 0):

```
const MyFunctionComponent = ({text}) => <Text>{text}</Text>;

MyFunctionComponent.displayName = 'HarmlessComponent';
MyFunctionComponent.propTypes = {text: PropTypes.string.isRequired};

export default React.memo(MyFunctionComponent);
```

Comment: Please format code in your answers using the tools provided. Code only answers can almost always be improved by explaining the code and how it solves the problem.